# Проблема с ImageField

Tags: python, django

Что хранит в себе ImageField в Django: саму картинку или путь к ней?

Comment: Путь к файлу, сохранённому в [default storage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#storages) (если не указан какой-то другой storage)